# In regression, why does having D=N-1 parameters in a model(N is the number of data points) mean that we can perfectly Interpolate the data points?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Reading through Murphy’s Machine Learning: An introduction.

Example provides some data and a polynomial regression model of the standard form
$f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w})= \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{\phi{(x})}$ is used where $\phi{x}=[1,x,x^2,...,x^D]$.

He then states the following:
“D=2 results in a much better fit. We can keep increasing D,and hence the number of parameters in the model, until $D = N-1$. In this case we have one parameter per data point, so we can perfectly interpolate the data.”

My questions are the following:
1)what does it mean to perfectly interpolate the data in this context? (How would we know that we’ve perfectly interpolated the data?)

2)why does having D=N-1 parameters mean that we can perfectly interpolate the data?

3)Why do we have to stop at D=N-1 parameters?

Comment: The statements are not generally true for statistical models.  They rely on special (yet well known) properties of polynomials that the audience of your text is assumed to be familiar with.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation for details.